# jQuery not returning jquery.closest().text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently having an issue with jQuery returning the text from the closest `td.index`. [Heres what I'm working with](http://jsfiddle.net/SaiyanToaster/0hcceau1/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.14.2/data/en_US/rune.json", function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        $.each(response.data, function (index, entry) {
            $('table.runes').append('<tr><td class="index">'
                    +index+ '</td><td class="icon"> \
                    <div style="width:48px;height:48px;background:url(./assets/runes/rune0.png) -' +entry.image.x+ 'px -' +entry.image.y+ 'px no-repeat"> \
                    </div></td><td class="entry-name">'
                    +entry.name+ '</td></tr> \
                    <tr><td></td><td class="entry-desc">'
                    +entry.description+ '</td></tr>'
                );
        });
    });
    jQuery("body").on("click", "td.entry-name", function() {
        var getText = $(this).closest('td.index');
        alert(getText.text());
    });
});
```

As you can see the table is generated using JSON/jQuery, and there is a `td` with the class name `index` which holds the ID number for each row.

When clicking on the `td.entry-name` it should look for the closest `td.index` and return the text that is inside it, which is an ID Number, as an alert. For some reason this doesn't work.

I wondered if by looking at the code if you could see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `td.index` is a sibling of `td.entry-name` not a ancenstor so use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead of [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
jQuery("body").on("click", "td.entry-name", function() {
    var getText = $(this).siblings('td.index');
    alert(getText.text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.siblings()` or `.prevAll()` instead of `.closest()`

```
var getText = $(this).siblings('td.index');
```

**[Working Demo with siblings](http://jsfiddle.net/nsyhxfgL/)**

or

```
var getText = $(this).prevAll('td.index');
```

**[Working Demo with prevAll](http://jsfiddle.net/7L2o3xtk/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var getText = $(this).parent().find('td.index');
alert(getText.text());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0hcceau1/2/)